# Add spinner text along with spinner in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, css, html

I am trying to add spinner text like 'Please wait while loading' along with dotted spinner. But the text is not displaying . It is displaying just a spinner. Can you identify what i am missing ?

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.Spinner}">
    <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
        <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-is-relative" role="alert">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>

            <p> please wait while loading </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: you will probably need to set a z-index to the p element where your text is to a greater value for it to diplay on top of the overlay/spinner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [spinner component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:spinner/example) already in lightning. You can use this then with a little css add your text in the style.

#### Component

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
    <lightning:spinner class="spins" size="large" variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading" />
</aura:if>
```

#### CSS

```
.THIS .spins::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Please wait while loading';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: calc(50% + 3em);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The top value is based on the fact i'm using the large size spinner, this can be tweaked if using another size. And it will give you something like:
[image]

Comment: One issue to be aware of with this approach, it makes translations difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 3):

**For LWC**

Sample result:

[image: Sample]

**HTML**

```
<div if:true={status.isLoading} class="slds-grid">
    <div class="loading-container slds-is-relative">
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>
    <div>
        Please wait while PipeLaunch is trying to guess the email address
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loading-container lightning-spinner {
  background: transparent;
}

.loading-container {
   min-width: 2.5rem;
   max-width: 2.5rem;
}
```

**Explanation**

The loading container class removes the background and the position relative, overrides the default centered position of the spinner component.
The grid layout will present the data in two columns, so we just need to specify a fixed with to the first column (there's other ways to do that like flex grow property)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This appears to be quite similar to existing answers, and is a _code dump_. Code dumps are of limited value to the community. Generally speaking, explaining _why_ and _how_ something works is as important as the solution itself.

Comment: explanation added

Comment: This is much better than adding content within the css

Answer (score 1):

By adding custom css in `<p>` tag

```
<div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
    <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-is-relative" role="alert">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>

        <p style="transform: translate(-32%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);width: 320px;text-align: center;"> please wait while loading </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
    <lightning:spinner class="spins" size="large" variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading" />
</aura:if>
```

CSS class should not have gap ::

```
.THIS.spins::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Please wait while loading';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: calc(50% + 3em);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This will give you desired result.