# LWC lightning-spinner not able to display the text

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am able to add a lightning-spinner in an LWC component, but I'm not able to display the text along with the spinner. I need some help regarding the same. I tried both alternate-text in HTML  & content in CSS file - both dint work.

HTML :-

```
<div class="exampleHolder">
    <template if:true={showLoadingSpinner}>
        <lightning-spinner  alternative-text="Fetching Fields of the Object......" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
</div>
```

CSS is as follows:-

```
.exampleHolder{
    margin: auto;
    content :'Fetching Fields of the Object......';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
```

Comment: `alternative-text` is displayed when the spinner is not loaded due to some reason/s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer on this post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240558/add-spinner-text-along-with-spinner-in-lightning-component) for aura component can be adapted for LWC as follows, you can try it

**HTML**

```
<template>
<div class="exampleHolder">
    <template if:true={showLoadingSpinner}>
        <lightning-spinner class="spins" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
</div>
</template>
```

**CSS**

```
 .spins::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Fetching Fields of the Object......';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: calc(50% + 3em);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: In case of dynamic message for different scenarios?

Comment: @AdityaVijay you can have several CSS classes with different content message, then use a getter in JS to toggle the class name based on the conditions